# Building concrete on top of wood

Tags: 7-days-to-die

I've built a house (8 x 10, 5 tall) out of wood and now I want to add another floor/level to it. I want to make the second level out of concrete. Will this cause any problems in terms of structural integrity? It would suck if it collapsed and crushed the contents of my house.

http://7daystodie.gamepedia.com/Structural_Integrity says:

> Vertical stability is infinite. You can stack 250 stone, tungsten, or concrete on a single Wood Frame.

But that doesn't tell me much about my question. Could I make the second level (walls and ceiling) out of concrete?

Comment: I don't think that weight apply's. I think its just blocks going sideways. You could also try creative mode testing that.

Comment: Seems to explain your question in this image. https://hydra-media.cursecdn.com/7daystodie.gamepedia.com/a/a4/First.jpg?version=7bb7e6deb9ad65ccba94e4c10c666be5][1]

Comment: Thanks, hopefully it won't collapse then. That image doesn't really tell me anything, unfortunately.

Comment: Why would you make the bottom wood anyway? The zombies will tear through it. The best option is to remake the bottom into concrete and the upper  half to be woord

Comment: Because that's not an option in the first few days, when I started building.. anyway, this kind of discussion is not really contributing towards answering the question.

Comment: Comments are for suggestions as well. They do not have to have the answer in them, but they must at least contribute to the tag.

Comment: Sure, but the point is that it's not related to the question. If you really wanted to know, this house is within a perimeter wall, so it could be built out of glass for all it matters. The question is quite clear; it's not "how can I improve my house?" The aim is to achieve a certain kind of aesthetic, as weird as it may sound.

Comment: The max load (as seen in the 7D2D wiki) is basically how much weight a block can support before it collapses. A regular concrete block has a max load of 90, a mass of 15, and a structural integrity of 6, meaning it can hold 6 more concrete blocks (6x15 = 90) before it will collapse. A wood frame has a max load of 24, so it will hold much less, not even two concrete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wood will not hold up a concrete floor, unless the outside edge of the floor (the blocks that are above the walls) are also concrete. (from the outside, you would see a horizontal layer of concrete and not wood.)

Wood frames do not have much structural integrity at all. A 2x3 wood structure that is 3 blocks high cannot even support a single layer of iron bars all the way around it. I had to upgrade them to at least scrap iron blocks before the iron bars would stop collapsing.

Edit: Adding some numbers.

A wood block (upgraded wood frame) has a max load of 24, a weight of 4, and a structural integrity of 6. (Max Load = weight X SI) So a single upgraded wood frame (wood block) can support 6 wood blocks (I believe including itself, so 5 other wood blocks, someone correct me if I'm wrong) before collapsing. Regular concrete blocks have a max load of 90, mass of 15, and a SI of 6, so it can also hold 5 other similar blocks before collapsing. However, if you put a much heavier block on the side of a wood block, (concrete block has mass of 15, but wood block can only support 24) so the wood frame will collapse as soon as you add the 2nd concrete block. While this may allow you to line the "inside layer" of your floor with concrete blocks, as soon as you start to fill in the center of the floor, it will collapse. In order to have a concrete floor, you need to use concrete in the outer layer (in line with the walls, as I mentioned above) to give the interior concrete blocks something to connect to.

I also believe that for an 8x10 structure, that you will need a center support beam of support, but maybe I'm wrong about that. I always add a center support beam for anything bigger than 7x7 so I don't add a forge or something and have the whole thing crashing down with all my stuff inside.